# In Ruby on Rails, Repeated Access to ActiveRecordModel Returns Same Object: Intended Behavior or Bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm encountering a peculiar behavior with my ActiveRecordModel in a Ruby on Rails application. Every time I access the model, it appears to return the same object instance. I'm unsure if this is standard behavior or a potential issue with my implementation.

Here's the scenario:

I have a class `MyModel` that inherits from `ApplicationRecord`. In this class, I have defined two class methods, `test` and `test2`. The `test` method filters `MyModel` records based on a specific condition and then calls `test2`. The `test2` method iterates over the collection, updates each record, and then attempts to find the same record by its ID.

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def self.test
    MyModel.where(some_column: "A").test2
  end

  def self.test2
    all.each do |my_model|
      my_model.update(some_column: "B")
      MyModel.find(my_model.id)
    end
  end
end
```

However, during this process, I encounter an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, which seems unusual. The exception message is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find MyModel with 'id'='the_id_of_record' [WHERE "my_models"."some_column" = $1])
```

This error suggests that after updating the record, the subsequent `find` operation is unable to locate the record. I'm trying to understand if this is expected behavior due to some ActiveRecord caching mechanism or a flaw in my approach. Additionally, I'd appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to handle this situation effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is intended. You're calling `test2` method on a relation which means it acts as a scope and not just a method call:

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L78-L80*

```rb
>> puts MyModel.where(some_column: "A").method(:test2).source
def #{method}(...)
  scoping { klass.#{method}(...) }
end
```

Note the method call is delegated through `scoping` method to `MyModel.test2`.

> Scope all queries to the current scope.
>
> ```rb
> Comment.where(post_id: 1).scoping do
>   Comment.first
> end
> # SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1 ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
> ```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-scoping*

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def self.test
    MyModel.where(some_column: "A").test2
  end

  def self.test2
    all.each do |my_model|
      my_model.update(some_column: "B")

      # NOTE: when you do this, `current_scope` is taken into account
      #       which you can take a look at:
      p "current_scope"
      p current_scope.to_sql
      MyModel.find(my_model.id)
    end
  end
end
#=>
# "current_scope"
# "SELECT \"my_models\".* FROM \"my_models\" WHERE \"my_models\".\"some_column\" = 'A'"
```

---

You can use `MyModel.unscoped.find(my_model.id)`, but I don't see why you need to do this. Also you can just not chain your method call to a relation:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def self.test
    MyModel.where(some_column: "A")
  end

  def self.test2 q
    q.each do |my_model|
      my_model.update(some_column: "B")
      MyModel.find(my_model.id)
    end
  end
end

>> MyModel.test2(MyModel.test)
```

Comment: The actual code is including `after_commit` with a method that `find` by id.
I guess it operates in the same way as you explain.

Thank you Alex, for your accurate and sophisticated answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to have some performance issue when having a lot of models to update. With more context, why you need to reload your model here, I could provide a better answer. Without knowing the context, I would suggest to just update all columns at once and than return all again.

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def self.test
    MyModel.where(some_column: "A").test2
  end

  def self.test2
    all.update_all(some_column: "B")
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: The question is not about performance. The OP is asking why the `find` call is failing.